# si7060 I2C temperature sensor with STM32 CubeIDE?

Tags: i2c, hal, stm32cubeide

I am trying to read an SI7060. It's my first time using i2c and it doesn't seem to work.
Do I make something wrong here?
[SI7060 datasheet](https://hu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/si7060-datasheet-1369253.pdf)

```
static const uint8_t REG_TEMP = 0xc1;
uint8_t buf[12];
HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;


buf[0] = REG_TEMP;
ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c3, TMP102_ADDR, buf, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(100);
if ( ret != HAL_OK ) {
    strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Tx\r\n");
} else {

    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c3, TMP102_ADDR, buf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    if ( ret != HAL_OK ) {
    strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Rx\r\n");
    }
}

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

Comment: When you say it does not seem to work, what happens? Does it trigger on "Error Tx", "Error Rx", both, or neither?

Comment: Nothing happens. No error. No received data.
IDuring debugging it seems that it returns a HAL_OK but there is no received message.

Comment: Good, it means the I2C addres should be correct, only the protocol isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet page 3 says how the I2C registers should be read and written, and the code does not do as the datasheet says. Some chips do work with the way your code is written, some chips do not even return an acknowledgement to the read sequence if the register write sequence is wrong.

Just use HAL_I2C_MEM_READ and HAL_I2C_MEM_WRITE to access the registers. You may also need to initialize the chip with correct register writes to wake it up and to auto-increment register address if you want to read multi-byte registers in one read operation.

Comment: I tried with the mentioned functions but I got the same result. After debugging there is no error and buf[0] = \0.
I tried to write 0x04 to the 0xc4 register to make a single conversion.


     buf[0] = 0xc4;   //To make a single conversion
     buf[1] = 0x04;   //To make a single conversion
       HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c3,TMP102_ADDR,buf[1],1,buf,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY );

Comment: The chip starts up in powerdown mode, so are you initializing the chip into active mode and trigger a conversion by writing the correct values into correct registers? If not, it has no valid temperature reading to send back to you. If you can read the chip ID register properly, problem is not the I2C communications, but what registers to write to wake up the part and make it do measurements.

Comment: I don't even know why I didn't start with reading the ID register. Unfortunately after reading the ID register the received data will also be \0. So the problem is the I2C communication.

Comment: "By default the part enters
the Autonomous Sampling Mode upon powerup. The sensor wakes up, performs a temperature conversion, updates the output accordingly, and then goes back to sleep.
"
According to this. There is valid measurement after powerup.

Comment: If it returns HAL_OK then I2C transactions should be fine. What is the slave address define you use? Do you have other I2C devices on the bus?